# HTTPPOST request always returns double and 0?

Tags: php, c++, http, post

i am having a weird issue. I am using wininet library to make a HTTP post request to my server but when i do so it returns the same thing twice with an 0.

Http post request code

```
BYTE* DoPostRequest(std::wstring ip, int port, std::wstring path, std::string data)
{
    HINTERNET hHttpSession, hHttpRequest, hIntSession;
    DWORD timeout;
    DWORD dwRead;

    hIntSession = InternetOpen(L"Somerandomshiz" //Utils::StringToWString(XorStr()).c_str()
        , INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);

    if (!hIntSession)
        std::cout << "hIntSession Faild" << std::endl;

    timeout = 300 * 1000;
    if (!InternetSetOption(hIntSession, INTERNET_OPTION_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT, &timeout, sizeof(timeout)) ||
        !InternetSetOption(hIntSession, INTERNET_OPTION_SEND_TIMEOUT, &timeout, sizeof(timeout)) ||
        !InternetSetOption(hIntSession, INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, &timeout, sizeof(timeout)))
        std::cout << "!InternetSetOption(hIntSession, INTERNET_OPTION_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT, &timeout, sizeof(timeout)) Faild" << std::endl;

    hHttpSession = InternetConnect(hIntSession, ip.c_str(), port, 0, 0, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, NULL);
    if (!hHttpSession)
        std::cout << "hHttpSession Faild" << std::endl;

    hHttpRequest = HttpOpenRequest(
        hHttpSession,
        L"POST",
        path.c_str(),
        0, 0, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);

    if (!hHttpRequest)
        std::cout << "hHttpRequest Faild" << std::endl;

    std::string szHeaders = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;\r\nContent-Length: ";
    szHeaders += std::to_string(data.length());

    if (!HttpSendRequestA(hHttpRequest, szHeaders.c_str(), szHeaders.length(), (LPVOID)data.c_str(), data.length()))
        std::cout << "HttpSendRequestA Faild" << std::endl;

    //payload
    const int BUFFERSIZE = 7 * 1000 * 1000; //7mb
    dwRead = 0;
    CHAR* szAsciiBuffer = new CHAR[BUFFERSIZE];
    memset(szAsciiBuffer, 0, BUFFERSIZE);
    InternetReadFile(hHttpRequest, szAsciiBuffer, BUFFERSIZE, &dwRead);

    InternetCloseHandle(hHttpRequest);
    InternetCloseHandle(hHttpSession);
    InternetCloseHandle(hIntSession);

    return (BYTE*)szAsciiBuffer;
}
```

My Call

```
auto response = (char*)g_pUtilis->DoPostRequest(
    L"localhost", 80, L"test.php",
    std::string("id=") + "231"
);
```

PHP Code

```
echo "test";
```

And what i get back - 
[Result Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBvSe.png)

EDIT: 
It seems to grab other information fine its only when i use PHP echo / just have php returning any thing. Any ideas? i cannot find much info on da internet.

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: 
Still having this issue cannot figure it out. 
so

```
echo "1234";
exit;
```

basically in browser is outputs 1234 but in my console using POST it returns - 1234234

0 // I have no clue where that 0 came from. 
[Raw Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBvSe.png)

This only seems to happen on namecheap.com servers. It works fine on OVH VPS web server as well as 000webhost.com / hosting24.com (same thing right? :P )

If any one has any idea whats going on plz help i dont want to spend more money
just because of this bug.

Comment: Any ideas? i am still stuck cannot figure this out!